# problems with php53-mcrypt brew

Tags: php, homebrew

While trying to install mcrypt for php53, using homebrew, I'm running into this error:

```
$ php -i
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpng15.15.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling libpng, switching to different versions of libpng, remove/reinstall php53-mcrypt, etc. I've now uninstalled both those with homebrew and it's giving the same error still. Haven't turned up any good results on google for solutions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What fixed it for me was doing a brew re-install of PHP itself, so here are the steps:

```
brew reinstall php53
```

then restart apache:

```
apachectl stop  
apachectl start
```